# How do you print 2 HTML pages in one .c/.cgi file?

Tags: c#, cgi

I need to print an HTML file that will ask for a password, and another HTML file that will parse it. I need to do it in one c file.

How do I link it? How can I make the program know that it needs to parse the data from the first HTML page, and print it at the same time?

I'm not using Perl, Python or anything else. Just plain c# and CGI.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just test to see if the password was sent: if it was, do your password-parsing page stuff. If not, display your first login page.

Comment: The two html pages were printing. I don't know what condition I should type to print it one at a time. :(

Comment: And one more thing, I first did two c codes, which is way easier than one, to check if it works. Then, I tried to combine it in one.

Comment: Do you know how to get the post params from the request? That is, if the password is sent, can you get it into a variable?

Comment: Yes. I used forms. I don't know what to put in the action attribute. I cannot link it back to the page because then I'm printing the first HTML page again, and the password will not be parsed.

Comment: No, do put the same page in the action attribute. Then, at the beginning of your CGI handler, just check to see if the form variable is populated. If it isn't then do your login page, if it is then do the 2nd page.